# Dynamic change image source in windows phone 7.1 apps

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have a list box in my app and a button inside that list box. I applied a image to that button (appbar.edit.rest.png icon). but when theme change to light, icon doesn't display...what should i do to dynamic change that icon when theme changed. Xaml code is as follows:

```
<ListBox x:Name="passwordSaferRecordsListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding EntityRecordInfoItems}" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12, 140, 0, 0" FontSize="40" HorizontalAlignment="Center" >    

<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="440">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock
                            Text="{Binding RecordName}"
                            FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeLarge}"
                            Grid.Column="0"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        <Button
                            Grid.Column="1"
                            x:Name="editTaskButton"
                            BorderThickness="0"                                
                            Margin="0"
                            Click="editTaskButton_Click" DataContext="{Binding}">
                            <Image Source="appbar.edit.rest.png"></Image>
                        </Button>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a viewmodel with an ImageUri:

```
private Uri imageUrl;

    public Uri ImageUrl
    {
        get { return imageUrl; }

        set
        {
            if (imageUrl != value)
            {
                imageUrl = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("ImageUrl");
            }
        }
    }
```

Then you go to your XAML and bind the image:

```
<Image  x:Name="BackgroundImage"  Height="50" Width="50" Stretch="Fill">
  <Image.Source>
       <BitmapImage UriSource="{Binding Path=ImageUrl,Mode=TwoWay}" />
  </Image.Source>
</Image>
```

I hope this will help you!